# handling a error in mysql using php caused by ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am submitting a form using ajax,

```
 function ajax_post() {
            // ...(code);
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://domain.com/submit_action.php";
        var vars = "element_1=" + ln + "&element_2=" + fn;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        hr.send(vars);
            // ...(code);
}
```

having the php exc the query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM ' . table. '
        WHERE ' . $db -> sql_build_array('SELECT', $data);
$result = $db -> sql_query($sql);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . table. ' ' . $db -> sql_build_array('INSERT', $data);
$db -> sql_query($sql);
```

In my above code, it will run. But when the 'fn' and 'ln' are the same or already exist in the db, then there will be a error. But because im using ajax to submit it, I stay on the current page of the form without getting a error, without knowing if the query exc or not.

Question is, is there a way to have php tell ajax what kind of error occured during the exc of query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried debugging in firebug ?

Comment: just did, but there are no errors reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anything echoed during your php script will be returned into the `hr.responseXML` and `hr.responseText` attributes.

Catch these 2 values within your `hr.onreadystatechange` callback, whenever the status is OK, to know what happened in your php.

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && (hr.status == 200)) {
        //do something with hr.responseText
    }
}
```

I personnaly systematically encapsulate my php answers inside a generic xml response, with a customized status: error/ok/business error, and a customized message, so I know what to do with it at the javascript layer.

In addition to this, I would suggest you catch the 1062 mysql error to know that the error is due to an already existing value, and raise a more user-friendly message.